# When exporting reactjs components as node modules to npm, do I include jsx or js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, reactjs

I have been creating some React.js components and publishing them as modules to npm.

I am using the following gulp task to convert all of my jsx components into js, using gulp-react:

```
var react = require('gulp-react');

gulp.task('react', function () {    
  return gulp.src('./jsx/*.jsx')
    .pipe(react({
      harmony: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});
```

So in my published module I have components in the js and jsx folder.

*My question is* which is it better to point the main file to in my package.json?

**js**

```
"main": "js/todo.js",
```

or **jsx**

```
"main": "jsx/todo.jsx",
```

I would assume if I point them to the jsx then they will need to have gulp-react installed, so would I add that into peerDependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, a special case of the classic "do I include build artifacts in my repo?". I tend to land on the side of pointing to JS files, since the point of a package/dependencies manager is that when you publish stuff others should be able to install and start using straight away, without having to think about dependencies by themselves. E.g:

I install my package on the command line:

```
$ npm install something
```

Open the Node `repl` and:

```
> var something = require('something');
undefined
> something.functionallity(1, 2, 3);
...whatever, but you wouldn't like an error now...
```

Comment: I am leaning towards this idea too, pointing to the JS files. thanks

Comment: But what about repeated dependencies? Consider that `parent` depends on `underscore` and `child` depends on `underscore` too. If we compile child, for example, using webpack, `underscore` will be included in the compiled file and be repeated in `parent`. What do you guys think about that?

Comment: That's kind of the point with how npm handles dependencies. If byte sizes are a concern, there's always `npm dedupe`: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

Answer (score 0):

Your `.js`, because then you can add something more in the pipeline and it'll be covered